# In a CLI Dart application, how does one run multiple Processes within a shared env?

Tags: dart, dart-io

Say I need to source a shell script via one of these two examples:

```
$ source setup.bash

$ . setup.sh
```

and then run a command included in PATH as a result of the previous step. How could you set up a method to perform these two steps using the Dart IO Process API? Is it necessary to manually pass the environment from one to the other somehow?

Comment: Can't you run both of the setup and the command you want to run in the same process?

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand how the Process.run method works. Is it not true that each invocation is completely isolated, with one command being run per invocation?

Comment: Have a look at the dart package dshell, it makes the stuff easy. Full disclosure I'm the author of dshell.